# Create user, error 500

Tags: magento-1.9, user

When creating a new user I get a error 500.

It seems that a class does not exist. I "grepped" for the name of the class but it does not show up anywhere else than the line in the error

```
"PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Pelago_Emogrifier' not found in app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Abstract.php on line 197" while reading response header from upstream, client: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: website.com, request: "POST /customer/account/createpost/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock:", host: "website.com", referrer: "http://website.com/customer/account/create/"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Error it seems there is no file `Emogrifier.php` in folder

```
magento Root/lib/Pelago/Emogrifier.php
```

Check file is exist or not if it is not there then download from fresh magento and put it to there.

Comment: It worked! Thanks. Do you have any idea when the lib was added? I wonder if I am missing more files now

Comment: It is added when you install magento patches or upgrade magento